# Rid Drop-down Arrow in Google Docs Table

Tags: drop-down-menu, border, google-docs

I want to rid the drop-down arrow for borders that displays in each cell of a table in Google Docs.  Annoying! Not a developer; just a user albeit v. strong one. Using Chrome (and sadly Windows 7 - long story but received free laptop with it and can't find free upgrade to Windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

Well put!  I have the same annoying problem.  In a small cell, the drop-down hides some of the text.  You must move to another cell to view the contents of the previous cell.  I hope someone provides an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).